# Response rendered as json in IE for browsable apis

Tags: django-rest-framework

On IE when i try to browse the rest apis, i am getting a application/json response instead of api (text/html) response (Returns html response on firefox). I am using django restframework 2.2.5 for this purpose.

I read through the documnets and understood that in order to overcome the problem of broken headers for IE we need to use TemplateHTMLRenderer explicitly in the view, so i have added the following to the class definition of my view but still i am getting a json response. Am i not doing it correctly or i am missing something else?

`class CustomReports(generics.GenericAPIView):`

```
  `renderer_classes = (renderers.TemplateHTMLRenderer)`
```

Can you please help in fix the problem so that i get html response in case of IE as well?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IE are you using?  I believe newer versions of IE should send correct `Accept` headers.

I probably wouldn't bother trying to fix things up to work around IE's broken behavior, but instead just make sure that you're including [format suffixes](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/format-suffixes.html) in your urls.  Then you can simply use the `.api` suffix to see the browseable API, or the `.json` suffix to see the plain json.

Eg instead of `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-root/`, use `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-root/.api`.

Comment: I actually tried this with couple of IE version..it seemed to work only with IE 9, but failed to work on IE8 and IE 10.

Comment: The accept header really should be correct [from IE9 onwards](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2011/02/10/fiddler-is-better-with-internet-explorer-9.aspx). Possible your IE10 test was in a compatibility mode.  If it really isn't working on IE10 I'd be interested to see what accept headers it's sending.

Comment: I just checked with IE10 standard view..it works on it but fails to work if it is in compatibility view. The accept headers that i get are:application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*